# How to Center Empty CSS Grid in Div and Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to center an empty CSS grid in a div. I need the grid to maintain a 16:9 aspect ratio and fill as much space as possible in the div. It is the only element in the div, and the div will change size since there are collapsible sidebars and a collapsible header in the full document.

The code below maintains the aspect ratio and fills the space, but when I try to center it the grid shrinks to the minimum size.

I have tried to center using `place-self: center center;` in the grid's CSS and `place-content: center center;` in the div's CSS, but both of those shrink the grid.

The container div does not have to be a grid if that makes it easier.

Code snippet :

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.canvas-grid {
  border: solid red 3px;
  max-width: fit-content;
  max-height: fit-content;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  margin: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 3px;
  grid-row-gap: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="canvas-grid"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could put in a snippet which has those collapsible features and am I right in thinking that the whole thing, including those collapsible items, must at all times be within the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Try 100vh height

```html
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="canvas-grid"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; /* Does nothing, already 100% height by default */
  height: 100%; /* 100% of auto does nothing */
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%; /* div is block by default already takes up 100% width */
  min-height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
  display: grid;
}

.canvas-grid {
  border: solid red 3px;
  max-width: fit-content;
  max-height: fit-content;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  margin: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 3px;
  grid-row-gap: 3px;
}
```